# Popping a key from dict() safely and in the most idiomatic way if a.) key doesn't exist or b.) key is not validated

Tags: python, dictionary, idioms

So, I am wondering. I have the following issue whereby a dictionary popping needs multiple checks and balances before doing something with the popped value.

I know that:

1. If key exists in dictionary then `dict.pop()` removes the element with given key from dictionary and return its value.
2. If given key doesn’t exist in dictionary then it returns the given Default value.
3. If given key doesn’t exist in dictionary and No Default value is passed to pop() then it will throw KeyError.

So, I felt that 3. I needed to firstly handle the `KeyError` exception. If it does then pop that key from the dictionary.

Then, 2 if the default is returned, perform no action.

Then if 1, perform some validation as the value needs to match a pre-defined string format (a Regex match for email, using Django's built in `from django.core.validators import email_re`, if the detail matters).

We have the following:

```
def some_function():
        try:
            email = account.pop('email', None)
        except KeyError as ex:
            return

        if not email:
            return

        if not email_re.match(email):
            return

        # Get/Update Or Create SurfAccount:
        surf_account, created = SurfAccount.objects.update_or_create(
            email=email,
            defaults=account
        )

        return surf_account, surfer
```

However, I'm not sure this is the most idiomatic way to perform a pop with validation in conjunction with a KeyError exception handler...because we can run into a TypeError if we call the function as this:

```
surf_account, surfer = some_function()
```

Bceause we are just "`returning`" out when validation fails...

Q.) So, what would be the most idiomatic way to perform such a dictionary popping with validation?

Comment: `email = account.pop('email', None)` You have already provided `None` as default value. So there is no chance that this statement would raise the `KeyError`

Answer (score 7):

`dict.pop(key, default)` will *never* raise a KeyError, if the key doesn't exist it just returns the default value. So your try:except: is not useful.

That aside using pop in such a way is fine, especially if you expect that case to be pretty common.

The issue with your second note is that the calling convention of your function is inconsistent, sometimes it returns two results and sometimes it returns none, so it's difficult to use.

- common Python idiom would recommend that your function raise an exception in case of an invalid email (whether missing or improper), that way the "happy path" always gets two values returned and the "unhappy path" is an exception handler, just replace your bare `return` by raising a suitable exception
- if you don't want to raise an exception for some reason, then you need to either change the result to always be a single value (e.g. a dataclass), or you need to change your error cases to return something like `None, None` (which is itself somewhat risky in a different manner than the current issue, as `if some_function()` will always pass).

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to actually return something, then you should return values according to what is expected to be returned, like:

```
try:
    email = account.pop('email')  # no default value here, so exception can occur
except KeyError as ex:
    return None, None
```

However, the better approach is to raise a specific exception:

```
try:
    email = account.pop('email')
except KeyError as ex:
    raise NoAccountFound() from ex
```

and let the caller handle it:

```
try:
    some_function()
except NoAccountFound:
    print("no account found...")
```

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `raise NoAccountFoundError`

Comment: @WindUpLordVexxos in python3 you can use `raise from` like this to have a traceback that shows the chain of exceptions

Comment: Ahhh, hmmm, ok so I tried it - and I'm using python 3.8 - and it threw another error ? What should the `NoAccountFound` class look like?

Comment: You have to define the new exception class. https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/user-defined-exception

Comment: Ahhh, ok so may class does inherit from the base exception class and just "passes" so not sure why it throws as error ...

Comment: Oh, d'oh, I was not `except KeyError as ex` just `except KeyError`